# Issues running the PL SQL function

Tags: function, plsql, parameters

I am trying to run the below function with some test data. When i am passing in_sales_model = 'C7.1' OR 'C3.2'it is failing. It executes correctly when i pass 'C32' or 'C27'..what do i need to change for the function to accept 'C7.1' or similar ?

```
create or replace FUNCTION                GET_VALID_ENG_MODEL_CSQ_1 
(in_sales_model in varchar ,in_mkt_segment_code in varchar, in_PRODUCT_TYPE in varchar, in_duty in varchar,in_emison_ind in varchar)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS tmp_eng_model_eomp VARCHAR2(32767);

BEGIN

    select /*+ optimizer_features_enable('11.2.0.3') */ distinct cic_model into tmp_eng_model_eomp
    from fbp_eng_mdl_ref
    where 
    PRODUCT_STATUS ='NEW' 
          end;


   RETURN tmp_eng_model_eomp; 

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     return '';
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       return '';
       RAISE;
END GET_VALID_ENG_MODEL_CSQ_1;
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. What exactly are you getting? Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. You need to post table definitions sample data, and  expected results. All as text - **no images** and expected results.

Comment: One suggestion (for testing  at any rate), remove the exception block, let any exception propagate out of the function.  As written if an exception is thrown your code catches it and discards it. BTW your raise statement in the ON OTHERS will never execute, the function execution terminates immediately with the just prior return statement.

Comment: Code you posted is useless. Moreover, it is invalid. What is that `end` doing at the end of the `select` statement? Why did you declare that many parameters if you don't use any of them? It is just confusing. Sample data would certainly help - simplify it! Finally, why did you use that hint? Is it *just because*, or ...? If you're beginner (it seems that you are), you'd rather let Oracle figure out how to execute code you write.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_VALID_ENG_MODEL_CSQ_1(in_sales_model      in varchar2,
                                                     in_mkt_segment_code in varchar2,
                                                     in_PRODUCT_TYPE     in varchar2,
                                                     in_duty             in varchar2,
                                                     in_emison_ind       in varchar2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  tmp_eng_model_eomp VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  select /*+ optimizer_features_enable('11.2.0.3') */
  distinct cic_model
    into tmp_eng_model_eomp
    from fbp_eng_mdl_ref
   where PRODUCT_STATUS = 'NEW';
  RETURN tmp_eng_model_eomp;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    return '';
END GET_VALID_ENG_MODEL_CSQ_1;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for trying. I corrected the code but still seeing the issue. Please see screenshot.